# Convert Access Left & Mid to SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ms-access, sql-server-2008-r2

I am currently trying to convert this query from Access into proper SQL.
The Left and Mid functions in the statement have me kind of baffled.

```
SELECT 
name, 
entnum

IIf(Left(Mid([entnum],4,3),1)=0,Mid([entnum],5,2),Mid([entnum],4,3)) as AGENCYCODE

FROM CUSTFILE
```

the entnum field's type is `varchar 15`

Any help with trying to understand this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What flavor of SQL is it?  Transact-SQL, or something else?

Comment: Just the standard version of SQL that comes with ssms for 2008 R2.

Comment: For future reference, that's called Transact-SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SUBSTRING` for `MID` and `LEFT`.  Conditional `IIF` statements exists in some dialects of SQL, but you  might be safer with a `CASE` statement.

Looking at your statement, I think it can be reduced to the following:

```
SELECT 
    name, 
    entnum,
    CASE 
        WHEN SUBSTRING(entnum,4,1) = '0' THEN SUBSTRING(entnum,5,2)
        ELSE SUBSTRING(entnum,4,3) 
    END agencycode
FROM CUSTFILE
```

Comment: Some minor typos - you're missing a comma after `entnum` and you've aliased `agencycode` inside the `CASE` statement when it should appear after `END`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT
  name,
  entnum,
  CASE
    WHEN LEFT(SUBSTRING([entnum], 4, 3), 1) = '0'
      THEN SUBSTRING([entnum], 5, 2)
    ELSE SUBSTRING([entnum], 4, 3)
  END as AGENCYCODE
FROM CUSTFILE
```

`SUBSTRING` is used exactly as `MID`.  The `CASE` statement allows you to specify multiple `WHEN..THEN` conditions as well as an `ELSE`.

Comment: The LEFT(SUBSTRING(entnum, 4, 3), 1) -- isn't that the same as the SUBSTRING(entnum,4,1)?

Comment: @sgeddes It is, but to avoid further complicating the translation from MS Access to SQL code I've left as much intact as possible.